# does tensorflow know the content of a constant tensor before runtime?

Tags: python, tensorflow

First example:

```
tensor = tf.ones([2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=tf.float32)
resize = tf.image.resize_images(tensor, tf.constant([10, 10]))
# <tf.Tensor 'ResizeBilinear:0' shape=(2, 10, 10, 5) dtype=float32>
```

The resized shape is [10, 10] in a constant tensor and tf is able to know the content, now next example

```
gather = tf.gather(tensor, tf.constant([2, 0, 1]))
# <tf.Tensor 'Gather_2:0' shape=(3, 3, 4, 5) dtype=float32>
```

Actually `2` is not allowed in the range of gather `[0, 2)`, since tf can know the content of a constant tensor like in the first example, why doesn't it raise an error about out of index here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because in general, even "`constant`" content can be changed through feeding.

An illustrative but useless example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(-1.)
b = tf.log(a) # surely this should fail?
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(b.eval({a: 1.})) # no error after all
# 0.0
```

In some critical places though, the python binding evaluates the content of a `tf.constant`: This is the case of `tf.image.resize_images`, when a constant tensor is provided as the `size` argument. The constant is then internally evaluated as a numpy array and is forbid to be fed other values.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
a = tf.constant((2,2))
print(a.eval({a:(3,3)}))
# [3 3]
tf.image.resize_images(tf.zeros((10,10,1)), a)
print(a.eval({a:(3,3)})) # ValueError: a may not be fed anymore
```

In those cases, there is no gain in providing a `tf.constant` over a simple numpy array.

Because evaluation of these constants need to happen on CPU and during graph construction (therefore somewhat defeating the purpose of putting them in the graph as `constant`), I assume they are limited to some situations where they impact the graph the most, in particular, when they are feed as tensor `shape`: The benefit of knowing the shapes is important both for debugging during graph construction and also somewhat for performance during execution.

By contrast, the shape of the output of `tf.gather` is affected by the number of indices, and not their actual values. What's more, `tf.gather` is most useful when the indices are unkown at construction time. If your indices are constant, you could indeed just write

```
tf.stack([tensor[i] for i in [2,0,1]])
```

which also provides bound checking.

Comment: then why in the first example, tf is able to know the shape of the resized tensor is [10, 10] even [10, 10] is the content of a constant tensor

Comment: thanks a lot for this question, but "some situations" seems to be ambiguous. The static graph is sometimes quite problematic and very hard to debug when the shape of a tensor is determined by the content of another one(like `tf.unsorted_segment_sum`).

Comment: Yes, it is ambiguous as the documentation does not explicitely mention where constants are freezed. However I feel it is still somewhat intuitive, esp. regarding the impact on output shapes.

Comment: Regarding `tf.unsorted_segment_sum`, it is the same situation as `resize_image`: shoud a constant tensor be provided as `num_segments` (which does impact output shape), it will be freezed. I think it is a  pretty consistent behavior.